# Hardware specific library in HAL

Tags: c++, cmake, embedded, hal

I'm doing a C++ (with cmake) embedded HAL layer and trying to add a library that is specific to some MCUs. Now the problem here is the access to the library functions from the upper layer.

My solution to this is to use cmake file for that specific board to define a macro, on which the library (and function) will be either excluded or included in upper layers. This requires to keep track of macro -> library and function pairs.

In sense of scalability, this isn't really a good way. Is there some more convenient way (from scalability and legacy point of view) to implement hardware-specific abilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a generic HAL where you include a library which is only available on some MCUs, then the only solution is dirty conditional compiler switches: `#ifndef SOMETHING #include "library.h" ...`. These quickly make the code unreadable, so they are always a last resort.

All of this does however suggest that you have a program design issue. Your program should work like this (calling order):

Application code -> HAL -> MCU specific driver

Where each of these 3 layers don't know anything of the contents inside the others. So naturally, there should not be anything MCU-specific inside the HAL. Rather, it should be inside the driver. Even in the rare case where the code in the driver is otherwise identical (for example when using different MCU derivatives of same family).

So in practice you'll end up with for example "spi_library.h" which is the HAL, and a number of drivers like "MCUX_SPI.c", "MCUY_SPI.c" where "MCUX" and "MCUY" are the different MCU part numbers.

In C++, this is typically done by implementing the HAL as an abstract base class, which each MCU implementation inherits. The HAL provides pure virtual functions which have to be implemented by the driver. (Not necessarily `public` ones.)

When publishing your HAL, you provide all the supported drivers. But the application should only link the relevant driver. The application need not know the contents of that driver, but it does need to know which MCU that is the target build.

Comment: Hi Lundin,

thanks for the explanation and suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Modern CMake operates with targets and properties.

So when you're building/exporting some specific library/target you can add [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/target_compile_definitions.html?highlight=target_compile#command:target_compile_definitions) with `INTERFACE`.

This will add definition to any target which will use this library during compilation.